# How to count for a substring over two tables in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have two tables

table1
id|name|next_field

table2
id|id_of_table1|whatelse

I do a msql query to get all entries of table1 and the number of entries in table2 who has table2.id_of_table1 = table1.id

This is my query - it works fine.

```
$select =array('table1.*', 'COUNT(table2.id) AS `my_count_result`',);
            $this->db->select($select);
            if($id!=false){ $this->db->where('id',$id);  }
            $this->db->from('table1 as t1');
            $this->db->join('table2 as t2', 't1.id = t2.id_of_table1');
            return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Now I have another field which has coma-separated data
table1.next_field = info1, info2, next,...

Now I want to check in the same way like the first query how often for example "info2" is as a part inside the table1.next_field

Is it possible, how?

Comment: *another field wich has coma-seperated datas table1.next_field = info1, info2, next,...* If you have the possibility to change your database structure please do it following [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), if you can't please mention it (and the reasons) in your question.

Comment: no i cannot change the database structure i need this field for adding a flexible number of entries in this field. Maybe there is another way i dont know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After all i decide to change my database structure to make the work and handle much easier.